# Absolute Coordinates for my Graphic Component

Tags: java, android, graphics

I am doing a project for a contest and in android for a tablet. By wanting to make the user interface more friendly I am using some meters to display speed, torque, temperature and current in a nice way.

So...I inserted the imageview's coresponding to the meters and now it's time to set that pins ( the place from where the indicator rises (it's a line on a circle) ). 
I have put my meters images in relative layouts and set parameters for everyone relative to screen resolution.
My problem now is that I want to center a image of that pin inside the meter. 
I tryed almost everything I can find to get the ablsolute coordinate x and y but no succes. I need something that can give me the exact location of the meter meening X and Y coordinates. To be more specific and I really hope I make myself undearstood I give the next example:

I have a screen...lets say 600x600 and I pinned a imageview in the center.
Now...I want to get the real coordinates for the imageview on the surface..so I want to get X = 300 - imageWidth/2, Y = 300 - ImageHeight/2 or something like that. So...When I put in a random position from xml layout using just the margin left and margin top parameters I didnt used hardcoded coordinates but now I need to get fixed coordinates beacouse I want to center anoter image inside the parent image.

Or another example: basicly I want to center a image inside a image and I think to do that I need fixed coordinates of the parent's image.

Thank you for your time, any critcs are much apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. It's not really my favorite but if I put my image inside a RelativeLayout and the other image centered in this RelativeLayout..it works like a charm.2 .  Anyone has a better ideea?